# How to make div have 100% height of parent, independent of children's size? Complex layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, display

I have the following layout on my webpage:

[image]

The left side, represented here by `D`, is perfect. There's a lot of content in there and it scrolls as it should. Even when the content grows, the height remains 100% of the webpage's height while the scroll increases.

The right side has some content on `B`. Everything fine as well. Using Bootstrap 4, `B` and `A` are `row` inside a `col` and, as such, have 50% share of the parent container.

The problem is that I would `A` to fill all of the remaining space while being scrollable independent of the number of `C`s inside it. This means that with 1 `C`, it should have its height as half of the page's height (as depicted in the picture) and by having 20 `C`s, it should occupy the same height (while being scrollable such that the user can see the 20th `C` by scrolling to the bottom of `A`).

So, I am being able to achieve vertical scrollability on `A` if I set a hardcoded height as `height=350px` but this is far from ideal since desktops have varying heights. On the other hand, if I don't set a height, `A`'s height become the height necessary to wrap all elements inside it, so with 4 `C`s the right-bg layout already surpass the left part of the webpage, causing a break on the overall layout.

```
<div class="right-bg">
<div class="container col" style="height:100%">
  <div class="row"> <!-- THIS IS B -->
    <div class="col"> 
      <div class="row" id="chart-div">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div class="row horizontal-menu-wrapper">      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container row ranking-container"> <!-- THIS IS A -->
    <div class="container rounded-card"> <!-- THIS IS C -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
          <div id="ranking-trophy-header" class="row card-header">
            <i title="General" class="fas fa-trophy header-icon"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11">
          <div class="row row-card">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
              <p class="ranking-percentage-value"> Top 1%</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col ranking-field">
              <p class="form-field">Position</p>
              <p class="form-ranking-value"><span class="absolute-ranking">#<span class="absolute-ranking-value">83</span></span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col ranking-field">
              <p class="form-field">Pool</p>
              <p class="form-pool-value">9470</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.left-bg {
  flex-flow: column;
  display: flex;
  width: 54%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.right-bg {
  flex-flow: column;
  display: flex;
  width: 46%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

.ranking-container {
  vertical-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -9999px;
  padding-bottom: 9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`d-flex`**, **`flex-column`**, and **`h-100`** for its parent. And **`flex-grow-1`** for the row that you want that it occupies all of the available space.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container d-flex flex-column h-100 bg-light">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col p-5 bg-danger"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row bg-info flex-grow-1">
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works as expected irrespective of how many `row` you have.

### https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RJVaKw

You need to use `bootstrap-4.1` because `flex-grow-1` does not exist in the earlier version of it.

---

Most of your style is unnecessary. You can achieve this with pure Bootstrap classes.

---

## Update

It does not work in Chrome. To fix the issue, use `flex-grow-1` for the column inside `flex-grow-1` row. And set its **`overflow-y`** to **`scroll`**. You may hide the scrollbars too.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.overflow-y-scroll {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/*hide scrollbar in webkit-browsers */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container d-flex flex-column h-100 bg-light">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col p-5 bg-danger"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row bg-info flex-grow-1">
    <div class="col flex-grow-1 bg-primary overflow-y-scroll">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jKmYdq

Comment: It works perfectly on Safari and Firefox. On Chrome, though, the `flex-grow-1` div grows above its sibling `row` (with `bg-danger`) overlapping it. How do I fix it?

Comment: @rgoncalv updated the answer. I hope it solves the issue.

Comment: I increased the top-margin and it seems to have achieved the desired effect in all browsers. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```html
<div class="container col" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; ">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give any block level element an explicit `height` and then add:

```
overflow: auto;
```

which will add a scrollbar to that element *if* the content of the element is taller than the element's own explicitly declared height.

Here is a layout similar to the one you have described above, using **CSS Grid**.

Note that vertical scrollbars automatically display in the areas **D** and **A** because the content within those elements is taller than the height of the parent elements themselves.

**Working Example:**

```css
main {
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
width: 80vw;
height: 80vh;
border: 6px solid rgb(191, 191, 191);
border-radius: 15px;
}

.a-area {
background-color: rgb(255, 63, 63);
}

.b-area {
background-color: rgb(255, 127, 0);
}

.c-area {
border: none;
background-color: rgb(63, 63, 63);
}

.d-area {
grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
}

main div {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border: 4px solid rgb(191, 191, 191);
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
}

main div h2 {
margin: 0;
padding-right: 6px;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 36px;
text-align: right;
}

main div p,
.c-area {
margin: 6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<main>
<div class="d-area">
<h2>D</h2>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
</div>

<div class="b-area">
<h2>B</h2>
</div>

<div class="a-area">
<h2>A</h2>

<div class="c-area">
<h2>C</h2>
</div>

<div class="c-area">
<h2>C</h2>
</div>

<div class="c-area">
<h2>C</h2>
</div>

<div class="c-area">
<h2>C</h2>
</div>

<div class="c-area">
<h2>C</h2>
</div>

<div class="c-area">
<h2>C</h2>
</div>

</div>
</main>
```